# Word choice for specifying the real estate properties in terms of sale and rent

Tags: word-request, verbs

What is the correct English word that I can use to specify the real estate properties in cases if it is intended for sale or for rent. I think I can't use

```
Type:sale or Type:rent
```

because when people read the word `Type` they expect a description of something like bedsitter, one bedroom, single e.t.c but nothing to do with whether it is for sale or rent. for this purpose, What is the correct way to describe the object properties in terms of its sale and rent?

Comment: What context do you want this for? If you want to indicate the category in an ad you can just say "For sale" or "For rent". If you're asking for a list of one or the other you can say "May I just have the rentals?" or "May I just have those for sale?" [Some websites](//www.realestate.com.au/) manage to present the choice in a drop-down list without actually labelling it...

Comment: @nnnnnn i thought there was one word i can use to group the two words, sale and rent.

Comment: I would classify this as List: sale, List: rent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at how sites like rightmove or zoopla get around this: They don't use a heading, instead they split their site into a "for sale" tab and a "to rent" tab. If you can avoid using any word, you should.

However the legal term that means "The nature of the contract that allows you to live at a property" is **Tenure**. Your tenure can be freehold or leasehold or a tenancy. The first two would normally be considered "for sale" the last is "for rent". But note, as above, popular websites avoid this type of technical language.